# Error 400 - "Required" on Google Storage

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm having a problem with Google Cloud Storage API. I'm using curl, but I get a 400 error like this:

> { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Required" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Required" } }

Unfortunately, I cannot find a solution, as on the internet there's nothing like "Required" error.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$GOOGLE_API_KEY = "My-API-Key";

$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/img.artphototravel.com/o?key=".$GOOGLE_API_KEY;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
  CURLOPT_POST           => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
    "uploadType"    => "media",
    "name"          => "test.jpg"
  )
));

//Headers
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: image/jpeg";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Can anyone help my to figure out a solution? Thank you so much.

Comment: which api? which docs are you looking at?

Comment: @delboy1978uk the code above is based on this docs: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/simple-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to what @Brandon mentioned, uploadType + name should be included in the URL. Also, you should be using Authorization: Bearer,Content-type as headers. Not an expert in PHP but this [sample](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics#upload-object-json) REST APIs might come useful when creating the request.

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @[OBJECT] \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]" \
    -H "Content-Type: [OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE]" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o?uploadType=media&name=[OBJECT_NAME]"
```

On a side note, have you looked into the Cloud Storage PHP library. Here is the [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/src/upload_object.php). Good luck

Answer (score 0):

`uploadType` is not a post field, it's a URL query parameter like `key`. Also, you don't want to use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. That implies that you are uploading form data, and the `media` uploadType is the type of upload in which you upload data directly without providing a separate metadata section.